# Replace spaces with new lines if part of a specific pattern using sed and regex with extended syntax

Tags: regex, sed, nlp, text-processing

so I have a text file with multiple instances looking like this:

`word.  word or words [something:'else]`

I need to replace with a new line the double space after every period followed by a sequence of words and then a "[", like so:

`word.\nword or words [something:'else]`

I thought about using the sed command in bash with extended regex syntax, but nothing has worked so far... I've tried different variations of this:

`sed -E 's/(\.)(  )(.*)(.\[)/\1\n\3\4/g' old.txt > new.txt`

I'm an absolute beginner at this, so I'm not sure at all about what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\.  ((\w+ )+\[)/\.\n\1/g' file
```

Replace globally a period followed by two spaces and one or more words space separated followed by an opening square bracket by; a period followed by a newline followed by the matching back reference from the regexp.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed! I didn't know \w existed.

Answer (score -1):

Your `sed` command is almost correct (but contains some redundancies)

```
sed -E 's/(\.)(  )(.*)(.\[)/\1\n\3\4/' old.txt > new.txt
#                                   ^
#                                   You forget terminating the s command
```

But you don't need to capture everything. A simpler one could be

```
sed -E 's/\.  (.*\[)/.\n\1/' old.txt > new.txt
```